# DevC++ is not reading typedef struct in my code

Tags: c

I'm currently making this program as an activity in class. There's an error popping up when I called the struct inside my main(). I'm posting a picture of the code and where DevC++ was saying where the error is:[here's the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9LyH.png)

Comment: Currently, you are not giving a name to the `typedef`-ed struct. You should try using simple struct examples before using `typedef`

Comment: You have to use this new variable later in the code instead of `studentRecord` which is the type of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

`studentRecord[5];` is like doing `int[5];`.

That will not work.

Provide a variable name.

```
studentRecord hi[5];
```